# stop javascript_include_tag from being escaped

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, view-helpers

I am upgrading a Rail 3 application and for some reason the line

```
  <%= javascript_include_tag :defaults %>
```

produces

```
&lt;script src=&quot;/javascripts/prototype.js?1292866092&quot; type=&quot;text/javascript&quot;&gt;&lt;/script&gt;
&lt;script src=&quot;/javascripts/effects.js?1292866092&quot; type=&quot;text/javascript&quot;&gt;&lt;/script&gt;
&lt;script src=&quot;/javascripts/dragdrop.js?1292866092&quot; type=&quot;text/javascript&quot;&gt;&lt;/script&gt;
&lt;script src=&quot;/javascripts/controls.js?1292866092&quot; type=&quot;text/javascript&quot;&gt;&lt;/script&gt;
&lt;script src=&quot;/javascripts/rails.js?1292866092&quot; type=&quot;text/javascript&quot;&gt;&lt;/script&gt;
&lt;script src=&quot;/javascripts/application.js?1292608980&quot; type=&quot;text/javascript&quot;&gt;&lt;/script&gt;
```

Adding a 'raw' infront of the tag works but I'm trying to figure out the real reason why it is doing this. The stylesheet tag above it works fine. I'm confused. Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The culprit was a plugin (semantic_form_builder) that overrides the default rails helpers. I don't think there is an update for it although it shouldn't take much to make it rails3 compatible.

I hope to move to simple_form in the future anyway.

Comment: My culprit was an old `easy-fckeditor` rails plugin. *shakes a fist* MONKEYPATCHIIIIING

Answer (score 1):

Rails 3 automatically escapes html for Xss protection instead of  <%= h .. %>  which was used in Rails 2.x.

Learn more about it http://railscasts.com/episodes/204-xss-protection-in-rails-3

Comment: I don't think it is supposed to rails helpers though… the stylesheet_include_tag helper works fine. However other form helpers 'text_field' are being escaped as well.

Comment: Well yeah it shouldn't, usually all helpers return already "html_safe" values, so this shouldn't be the case.